# How to get the ID from DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I am trying to save the changes I make when I select a different value from the DropDownList. But I am getting this error

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String [ArgumentNullException:
>   Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String]
>   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   +10722118    System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +145    System.Int32.Parse(String s) +23

I think the problem is its not finding the ID of the value in the DropDownList so it catches on this line in the update statement `Trailer.UpdateTrailer(int.Parse(TrailerID),`

```
  protected void ddlTrailerLoc_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList ddlTrailerLoc=sender as DropDownList;
            if (ddlTrailerLoc != null)
            {
                ddlTrailerLoc.SelectedValue.ToString();

                Trailer.UpdateTrailer(int.Parse(TrailerID), Company.Current.CompanyID,txtTrailerReg.Text,ddlTrailerLocation.Text);
            }
        }
```

How do I get the ID of the value I select from the DropDownList?

Here's the code to populate the DropDownList

```
protected void PopulateDDLs(DropDownList ddlTrailerLoc)
    {
        DataSet dsTrailerLocation = DataUtils.GetAllGenSmall(Company.Current.CompanyID, "Description", "", 1, false, "Description", false, "TrailerLocationNOCODE", 0);
        if (dsTrailerLocation.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ddlTrailerLoc.DataSource = dsTrailerLocation;
            ddlTrailerLoc.DataValueField = "Description";
            ddlTrailerLoc.DataTextField = "Description";
            ddlTrailerLoc.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            ddlTrailerLoc.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("No Locations Entered", "0"));
        }
    }
```

I know this `ddlTrailerLoc.DataValueField = "Description";` should be set to TrailerID or something but it will only work when it is Description. Changing this makes the DropDownList display the wrong values

Comment: It is not clear from your example where the TrailerID variable is initialized.
You may need to explicitly initialize it in your event handler, like this: TrailerID=((Trailer)ddlTrailerLoc.SelectedValue).TrailerID, where Trailer is the class of your DropDownList items

Comment: set the  DropDownList Value and Text Field  as follow ddlTrailerLoc.DataValueField = "Trailer_ID"; // id field which you want 
ddlTrailerLoc.DataTextField = "Trailer_Name";

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing with the information you've provided, but should this line:

```
ddlTrailerLoc.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

actually be:

```
TrailerID = ddlTrailerLoc.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Otherwise not sure from that code where TrailerID is set.

Comment: Yes I have tried that but it causes the error `Input string was not in a correct format.` because it sets the trailer location which is a string to the id which is int. TrailerID becomes "test" from the DropDownList but it should be a number

Comment: So why is it "test" when it should be a number? How do you populate the DropDownList?

Comment: I think (as the user stated above) you need to check the population of the DropDownList. You would normally expected the 'Text' property of the ListItem to be 'test', rather than the value (which as you say, are expecting to be an integer).

Comment: @Hysteria86 I have put the code for populating the DropDownList into my question

Comment: You appear to be using "Description" for both the Value and Text fields of the DropDownList items. I'm assuming the value "Description" is 'test.'

For ddlTrailerLoc.DataValueField you should be using one of the fields from your dataset that returns a unique integer value (a TrailerID or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected void ddlTrailerLoc_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList ddlTrailerLoc=sender as DropDownList;
string value = "".
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlTrailerLoc.SelectedValue.ToString())
            {
                value = ddlTrailerLoc.SelectedValue.ToString();

                Trailer.UpdateTrailer(int.Parse(TrailerID), Company.Current.CompanyID,txtTrailerReg.Text,ddlTrailerLocation.Text);
            }
        }
```

and then assign value to whenever you need to use it. Like TrailerID. I assume this is what you are trying to achieve. If so, you can assign TrailerID to ddlTrailerLoc.SelectedValue.ToString(); and then declaration for string value is unnecessary. In this case:

```
protected void ddlTrailerLoc_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DropDownList ddlTrailerLoc=sender as DropDownList;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlTrailerLoc.SelectedValue.ToString())
{
TrailerID = ddlTrailerLoc.SelectedValue.ToString();
Trailer.UpdateTrailer(int.Parse(TrailerID), Company.Current.CompanyID,txtTrailerReg.Text,ddlTrailerLocation.Text);
}
}
```

Comment: Setting `TrailerID = ddlTrailerLoc.SelectedValue.ToString();` causes the error Input string was not in a correct format. because it sets the trailer location which is a string to the id which is int. TrailerID becomes "test" from the DropDownList but it should be a number